# XML parsing in apex salesforce

Tags: xml, soap, xml-parsing, salesforce, apex-code

I am getting xml with special character from a webservice call as a response. Can you please suggest me that how can parse this or how can i convert xml that contains special character in actual xml format.

thanks,
vivek

Comment: i have an xml in string format and i haven't tried anything yet.

in my xml lessthan symbol and greaterthan symbol comes in special character form like lt; and gt;. I have to get actual xml with less than and greathan symbol.

Comment: Post your code so far.   Also see my answer to another question that shows two ways to handle XML documents.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13675702/basic-xml-parsing-issues-cannot-find-node-names-via-java-xmlstreamreader-method/13686520#13686520